# Find if an array's elements are in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = ["3","5","4","6"];
arr.sort();

var flag = 0;

for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] - arr[i-1] != 1 ) {
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}

if(flag == 1){
    alert('not in sequence');
}else{
    alert('in sequence');
}
```

Here, the loop breaks only if the array is not in sequence.

I want to break the loop if an array is in sequence.

Here's why.

I have 4 arrays. I want to end the loop if any one of the 4 arrays is in sequence

```
var arr1 = ["4","1","3","5"];
var arr2 = ["5","2","3","6"];
var arr3 = ["1","5","3","6"];
var arr4 = ["1","5","3","4"];


arr1.sort();
arr2.sort();
arr3.sort();
arr4.sort();


var flag = 0;


for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){

  if(flag == 0){
    for(var j = 1; i < eval('arr'+i).length; j++) {
          if(eval('arr'+i)[j] - eval('arr'+i)[j-1] != 1) {
             flag = 0;
         }else{
             flag = 1;
             break;
         }
    }
  }

}


if(flag == 1){
    alert('in sequence');
}else{
    alert('not in sequence');
}
```

Here, I'm trying to set flag to 1 if in sequence so that it does not enter the loop again.

It's always printing `in sequence`.

Comment: just keep reference to the prior value, if it is not <= current value flag it.

Comment: @nick Please elaborate. I tried what you said. No luck. Same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate your arrays using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). As soon as one of them is in sequence (`inSeq()` returns `true`), `Array#some` will return the `true`. Of all of them will fail, `Array#some` will return `false`. I'm using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in the `inSeq()` function to check that the elements increment. If an increment is not `1`, the loop returns `false` immediately:

```js
var arr1 = ["4", "1", "3", "5"];
var arr2 = ["5", "2", "3", "6"];
var arr3 = ["1", "5", "3", "6"];
var arr4 = ["1", "5", "3", "4"];

function inSeq(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; }) // the sort function is needed because you use strings instead of numbers, and it will be sorted lexicaly without the function.
    .every(function(n, i, arr) {
      return i === 0 || n - arr[i - 1] === 1;
    });
}

var result = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4].some(inSeq);

console.log(result);
```

And the shorter ES6 version using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
const arr1 = ["4", "1", "3", "5"];
const arr2 = ["5", "2", "3", "6"];
const arr3 = ["1", "5", "3", "6"];
const arr4 = ["1", "5", "3", "4"];

const inSeq = (input) => input.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .every((n, i, arr) => i === 0 || n - arr[i - 1] === 1);

const result = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4].some(inSeq);

console.log(result);
```

If you want to get the 1st array with a sequence, `Array#some` won't help you (unless you add some ugly code), as it returns a boolean. You can use a simple `for` loop:

```js
var arr1 = ["4", "1", "3", "5"];
var arr2 = ["5", "4", "3", "6"];
var arr3 = ["1", "5", "3", "6"];
var arr4 = ["1", "5", "3", "4"];

function inSeq(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; }) // the sort function is needed because you use strings instead of numbers, and it will be sorted lexicaly without the function.
    .every(function(n, i, arr) {
      return i === 0 || n - arr[i - 1] === 1;
    });
}

function findArrWithSeq(arrs) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arrs.length; i++) {
    if(inSeq(arrs[i])) {
       return i;
    }
  }
  
  return null;
}

var result = findArrWithSeq([arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Cool, and how to find which array has the sequence? Just the number.. So that I can use it elsewhere. If it returns "1" then I will know it's arr1. Like that.

Comment: I've added it to the answer's end. Next time please declare exactly what you want in the question.

Comment: Sure. But it's outputting 0 always.

Comment: Of course - I've changed the 1st array to a sequence (index 0).

Comment: Yes. I guessed that. But did you check that with second array by making it a sequence and not the first array? Even for that, it's printing 0.

Comment: Now the 2nd is the sequence. Look at the index. If the 1st is a sequence, and the 2nd is the sequence, you'll only get the 1st by the logic you wanted.

Comment: Cool.. Got it!.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by number, not by string and check every item in the innter array and return the result to the outer check of the array.

```js
var arr1 = ["4", "1", "3", "5"],
    arr2 = ["5", "2", "3", "6"],
    arr3 = ["1", "5", "3", "6"],
    arr4 = ["1", "5", "3", "4"];

function inSeq(arr) {
    arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });      
    return arr.every(function (a, i, aa) {
        return !i || +aa[i - 1] + 1 === +a;
    });
}

var result = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4].some(inSeq);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way to check if elements of the array are in sequence using every

```js
var arr1 = ["4", "1", "3", "5"];
var arr2 = ["5", "2", "3", "6"];
var arr3 = ["1", "5", "3", "6"];
var arr4 = ["1", "5", "3", "4"];
var inSeq = input => input.sort().every((x,i,arr) => i !== 0 ? x - arr[i - 1] === 1 : true);
var result = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4].some(x => inSeq(x));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the answer in similar form to your original (though moving logic to functions) you can use the following:

```js
var arr0 = ["4", "1", "3", "5"];
var arr1 = ["5", "2", "3", "6"];
var arr2 = ["1", "5", "3", "6"];
var arr3 = ["2", "5", "3", "4"];

var allArrays = [arr0, arr1, arr2, arr3];

function checkSequenced(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] != 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};

function findSequencedArrayIndex(allArrs) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (checkSequenced(allArrs[i])) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

var firstSequencedArray = findSequencedArrayIndex(allArrays);

if (firstSequencedArray >= 0) {
  console.log('First sequenced array index: ' + firstSequencedArray);
} else {
  console.log('No arrays in sequence');
}
```